# What are the empty lists in dirname of os.walk?

Tags: python, python-3.5, os.walk

When using python 3.5 `os.walk()` and looking at the dirname output I get a lot of empty lists (returned `[ ]`).  I have no idea why.

```
import os
tdir = '/home/pontiac/testdir'

gen0 = os.walk(tdir)
print(next(gen0)[1])
print(next(gen0)[1])

gen1 = os.walk(tdir)

for ea in gen1:
    print(ea[1])
```

Output:

```
['t2', 't1']

[]

['t2', 't1']

[]

[]
```

Comment: What's the *things* in `/home/pontiac/testdir`?

Comment: testdir -  directories t1 and t2 and no files.  t1 and t2 - have no sub directories and no files.

Comment: Got it.  I was just looking it over and figured that out and can now see, after reading your comment how that would be useful info..  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk):

> `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)` 
>   Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down
>   or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top
>   (including top itself), it yields a **3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames,
>   filenames)**.
>
> **dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. dirnames is a list of
>   the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..').
>   filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in
>   dirpath**. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components.
>   To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in
>   dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

Since `testdir` has only two empty directories `t1` and `t2`, so you will get :

```
>>> import os
>>> t = '/home/pontiac/testdir'
>>> for root, dirs, files in os.walk(t):
    print root, dirs, files


/home/testdir ['t1', 't2'] []
# ^rootdir     ^dirs list  ^files in rootdir 
/home/testdir/t1 [] []
/home/testdir/t2 [] []
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `os` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) what `os.walk` returns is a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`.

Let's say you have a directory `testdir`:

```
testdir
      |- dir1
      |    |- file3.txt
      |- dir2
      |- file1.txt
      |- file2.txt
```

Then looping over generator returned by `os.walk('path/to/testdir')` will produce the following tuples:

```
('path/to/testdir', ['dir2', 'dir1'], ['file3.txt', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt'])
('path/to/testdir/dir2', [], [])
('path/to/testdir/dir1', [], ['file3.txt'])
```

Since you're extracting first elements from the 3-tuples and getting empty lists, that means these are directories that contain no subdirectories in them.

Answer (score 0):

The call `os.walk` returns a tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. You print the `[1]` element of this tuple, `dirnames`, which is the list of subdirectories in a given directory. Your directories `t1` and `t2` apparently do not contain any subdirectories, hence the empty lists.

Comment: This turns into a lot! of empty lists when I walk over a directory that has a fair amount of depth to it.  I get 30 + in a row,  I'm confused about what is the point of this.  If I am trying to use this part os.walk, and am looking to get the directory names, if a directory has no subdirectories I don't need the none existent names?